# Duplicating a TABLE using Microsoft SQL Server Management

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Need to duplicate a TABLE using `Microsoft SQL Management Studio 2008`

The TABLE needs to duplicate all table row (Primary Key) ID as well.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In SSMS open a new query window and then do something like this:

```sql
SELECT * INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
```

Change `NewTable` to the name that the new table should have. Change `OldTable` to the name of the current table.

This will copy over the basic table structure and all the data. It will NOT duplicate any of the table constraints; you will need to script those out and change the names in those scripts.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work at first because I created the query by clicking databases.  This creates the query in the master database, which didn't work.  I got an error saying the object 'MyTable'  didn't exist.  When I created the query in the database that contained the table, it worked fine.  Just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 18):

An easy way to copy a table and all of it's data:

```
SELECT * INTO 
    [DATABASE_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[NEW_TABLE_NAME] 
FROM 
    [DATABASE_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[OLD_TABLE_NAME]
```

> The SCHEMA_NAME is often `dbo`

Answer (score 12):

To duplicate a table and the data rows in the table, right-click on the database that contains the table you want to duplicate, then click 'Tasks' then 'Import Data...". See the screenshot below for visual representation. Then, follow the instructions in the "SQL Server Import and Export Wizard." Select the table to be duplicated as the 'source' and write in a made-up table name of your choice for the 'destination'. When finished on the last screen (see screenshot below), click 'Next', then 'Finish' and the Wizard will show you the progress of the data transfer until complete.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This also allows copying tables from one server to another! +1

Comment: This works really easily, with no surprises regarding table structure and column definitions, however in my case, it was crazy slow for a large table. 150M records x 30 columns took ~12 hrs.

Comment: if you want to duplicate a table and maintain the default values and stuff... you should first ```right click``` your **source table**, then ```script table as``` ```create to``` ```new query window```. In the command you get, rename the table to create and update all the references that might be found within the command string. Then do as suggested in this answer to copy the data over!

Answer (score 2):

One way to copy the table structure (including default values) but NOT the actual table values is the copy / paste solution that is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337553.aspx). It works for Management Studio 2005 upwards. You just have to select all columns in the design then Edit -> Copy. Create a new table and the Edit -> Paste.

Comment: question asks for data to be copied as well