# SQL Server - Create Copy of Multiple Tables in Same Database

Tags: sql-server

I need to duplicate several tables in a single database.  Basically we have an old dot net nuke portal that needs to be split and our host limits us to a single database.  So we just want to take the existing tables but copy them with an exact duplicate but different table prefix name (e.g. EEPTL_Users to JBPTL_Users).

I can use 'script to - create' to make the proper table structure but how do I do the proper inserts when I **need** to specify the primary keys but want the column to be an auto-incrementing identiy?

Is there a tool for doing what I need?

Comment: A very similar question was asked earlier today: [Duplicating a TABLE using Microsoft SQL Server Mangement.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602346/duplicating-a-table-using-microsoft-sql-server-mangement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table name] ON

INSERTS

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table name] OFf
```

Comment: You've got it backwards. You want to turn IDENTITY_INSERT ON first to insert explicit values, then turn it OFF when you're done.

Comment: I read it as he wants to insert without the identity, and after the copy he wants it to function with identity.

Comment: @Brett: I think you read it correctly. Turning IDENTITY_INSERT ON allows you to specify an explicit value for the identity column. Turing IDENTITY_INSERT OFF forces you to allow the identity column to auto-increment. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Comment: this looks helpful.  going to hold out for some miracle solution before accepting though :)

Comment: @eyston - if this isn't exactly what you want, what sort of miracle solution are you looking for?

Comment: @Brett - right-click table, give new name, have it copied for me!

Comment: oops, Joe is correct on the order. My fingers are faster than my brain :)

Comment: can you fix the order so its clear for anyone who gets this by a search?